# I have rows with duplicate id but these duplicate rows may have more columns filled. How can I delete the duplicate row with lesser data in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

TLDR: is there a way to see which duplicate ID row has more columns filled and delete the one with lesser columns filled?

Here I want to keep the second occurrence of the duplicate ID (AB) since it has more data, as the first occurrence is blank for Age. Realistically, my df has more than 30 columns and the problem is similar to this.

| PatientID | Age | Married | Height | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | NaN | 1 | NaN | 63 |
| AB | 32 | NaN | 21 | 63 |
| BC | 91 | NaN | 153 | NaN |
| BC | 91 | 1 | NaN | 91 |

**I want OUTput to be**

| PatientID | Age | Married | Height | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 32 | Nan | 21 | 63 |
| BC | 91 | 1 | NaN | 91 |

Comment: `Realistically, my df has more than 30 columns and the problem is similar to this.` - Can you add 5 columns DataFrae to question with expected ouput?

Comment: I've added the input and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If need first non missing value per `PatientID` use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
#your sample data
print (df)
  PatientID   Age  Married  Height  Weight
0        AB   NaN      1.0     NaN    63.0
1        AB  32.0      NaN    21.0    63.0
2        BC  91.0      NaN   153.0     NaN
3        BC  91.0      1.0     NaN    91.0

df1 = df.groupby('PatientID', as_index=False).first()
print (df1)
  PatientID   Age  Married  Height  Weight
0        AB  32.0      1.0    21.0    63.0
1        BC  91.0      1.0   153.0    91.0
```

But problem is if there are multiple non unique values per `PatientID` in some column, then ouput is also first  values:

```
#changed data sample
print (df)
  PatientID   Age  Married  Height  Weight
0        AB   NaN      1.0     NaN    63.0
1        AB  32.0      NaN    21.0    63.0
2        BC  90.0      NaN   153.0     NaN < 90 per BC
3        BC  91.0      1.0     NaN    91.0 < 91 per BC


df1 = df.groupby('PatientID', as_index=False).first()
print (df1)
  PatientID   Age  Married  Height  Weight
0        AB  32.0      1.0    21.0    63.0
1        BC  90.0      1.0   153.0    91.0 <  91 is lost
```

So need cusom lambda function for avoid lost, there are no another non unique data in another columns, so NaNs are created:

```
f = lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y.dropna().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
df2 = df.set_index('PatientID').groupby('PatientID').apply(f).droplevel(1).reset_index()
print (df2)
  PatientID   Age  Married  Height  Weight
0        AB  32.0      1.0    21.0    63.0
1        BC  90.0      1.0   153.0    91.0
2        BC  91.0      NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: what if the df has many columns, is there a way to see which duplicate row has more columns filled?

Comment: @AdeebShaik - it depends of data, can you change data sample?

Comment: yes, I can change the data sample, but can you tell me what if changing the sample isnt possible

Comment: @AdeebShaik - Answer was edited.